How to resolve path with emoji in src? Next.js
I didn't expect it to be a problem to get an images with emojies in their paths:
/img/shops/main/text.webp
/img/shops/main/text.jpg
/img/shops/main/text.jpg
/img/shops/main/text.webp
/img/shops/main/(TOMAT).jpg

and if am trying to use it in src like:
<img src={`/img/shops/main/text.webp`}/> // or other pathes

it returns 404 in browser : %F0%9F%99%82text%F0%9F%99%82.webp:1 GET http://localhost:3000/public/img/shops/main/%F0%9F%99%82text%F0%9F%99%82.webp 404 (Not Found)
Paths without emojies works well
I tried some encode and decode methods such as encodeURIComponent, encodeUri and other, but unfortunately I was never able to get an image as expected

What happens if you use xn--text-el53c.webp instead of text.webp? The reason I'm asking - after reading this Wikipedia article, I discovered this. So, perhaps using a library which translates emojis into Punycode would do what you want.
